# EXTJS 4 : how to get combobox value with out determine combobox id

Tags: extjs

```
var StaticComboBox = Ext.define('MyApp.view.ComboBoxType', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
  mode: 'local',
  fieldLabel: 'Type',
  labelWidth: 50,
  triggerAction: 'all',
  editable: false,
  valueField: 'value',
  displayField: 'label', 
  data: [
               {value: 0, label: 'By Vehicle'},  {value: 1, label: 'By Route'}
          ] ,
  initComponent: function() {
    this.store = new Ext.data.Store({
      fields: ['value', 'label'],
      data: this.data
    });
    StaticComboBox.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
  },
  listeners: {
        change: function (combo, value) {
        var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('dailywindow gridpanel[name=mydailychartgrid]')[0];
        if (grid != null){
            if (value == 0) {
            //grid.reconfigure(VehicleStore_Chart,VehicleModel)
            grid.reconfigure(VehicleStore_Chart);
            grid.columns[1].setText('Plat No');
            grid.columns[1].dataIndex = "Plat_No"
            grid.columns[1].width = 100
            }else{

            //grid.reconfigure(RouteNameStore_DailyChart,RouteModel)
            grid.reconfigure(RouteNameStore_DailyChart)
            grid.columns[1].setText('Route Code');
            grid.columns[1].dataIndex = "Route_Code"
            grid.columns[1].width = 100
            }
        }
        //alert(value);
        }
  }

});

var c = new StaticComboBox();
c.setValue(0);
```

how do i get the combobox value without using determine id in combobox ?
`Ext.getCmp("ComboBoxType").getValue()` does not work.

Comment: you should give an id, like `id: 'myCombo'` in the combobox definition then you can use with getCmp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to use an id, use [`itemId`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-itemId) instead.

```
var val = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('ComboBoxType#yourItemId')[0].getValue();
```

the advantage of `itemId` is that they don't need to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should add `'id'` property to combobox and then use the `'Ext.getCmp('componentId')'`

or

Assign `'name'` property to it and use the `componentquery`.